# Grails 6 - create-app and create-restapi produce applications that fail to build

Tags: grails

I am creating a new empty grails 6 project (have tried version 6.1.2, 6.1.1, 6.1.0, 6.0.0) via the create-restapi command per their example:

```
grails create-restapi -i bookstore
```

the resulting project fails to build and recommends running

```
gradle dependencies
```

gradle dependencies shows 2 issues as follows:

> Configure project :
> Cannot resolve reloading agent JAR: Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.18 because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.grails.plugins.views-json', version: '3.1.1']

> Failed to apply plugin 'org.grails.plugins.views-json'.
> Could not create task ':compileGsonViews'.
> > Could not create task of type 'JsonViewCompilerTask'.
> > java.lang.InstantiationException (no error message)

not sure if related but coming from previous versions of grails i was surprised these commands did not create a domain folder inside grails-app.

i have tried with all the grails 6 versions and i get this flavor of error on them all. also tried create-app instead of create-restapi and same result - build failure and the above output from gradle dependencies. Tried also creating thru Intellij IDEA Grails Application Forge with the same result. I feel like im missing something simple but i cant figure it out.

Anyone else experience this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to the use of gradle instead of ./gradlew in my project. Though configured to use gradle wrapper, my Intellij seems to ignore it.

'gradle dependencies' was failing but './gradlew dependencies' works

likewise './gradlew bootRun' successfully starts the application.

in the Intellij run configuration, i was not able to get the Configuration of type "Grails" to call gradlew or start the project. This works fine with all previous versions of Grails i have (2, 3, 4, 5) but i have not been able to get it to work with grails 6.

instead. i made a Run configuration of type 'Gradle', and had it run 'bootRun' .

Now i am able to run the Grails project (6.1.2) using the run and debug buttons in Intellij.